# C++: how to end while(cin >>)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code I expected to repeat my input in uppercase versions of the letters I input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<string> Capital;
    string word;
    while (cin >> word) {
        Capital.push_back(word);
    }

    for (auto& a : Capital)
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            toupper(a[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I give this program input on the command line, and then end input with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + D, it prints nothing ([this is what my console looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJiEk.png)). What am I doing wrong?

input:

```
asf sdf df dafsaf  af
```

output:

Comment: You're not printing anything. Try using `cout` to print the words, after you've saved the result of uppercasing every character in every word with something like `a[i] = toupper(a[i])`

Comment: Also, for future reference: very, very few people monitor the c++11 tag. It's used to add detail to a c++ tag, which is what most c++ people watch. Use c++11 *and* c++ together, or c++ alone. Using only c++11 gets you very, very few views.

Comment: for(auto a: Capital)
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            cout<<a<<endl;
        }

Comment: And I add the code like this, but when I press command + D it did not print anything but repeat what I had just input.In addition the project did not exit.